# can i use the unique command in c++ to get frequency

Tags: c++, vector

I want to to get the frequency of words stored in a vector. I have Googled my question numerous times and not go something that would work for me. I have found a site where someone says to use the `unique` command to count the frequency of words but I can not find any examples of how this is done.

Comment: Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: [Good timing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616929/convert-array-to-new-array)

Comment: i am not using a book i say it on this website [link](http://compgroups.net/comp.soft-sys.matlab/Counting-Number-of-Occurrences-of-Each-Number-in-a-Vector)

Comment: @bobthemac That link isn’t about C++ at all.

Comment: And no, you cannot use `unique`, however you can use `count` (if looking for a specific word) or even a simple iteration through the vector with an insert into a map.

Comment: [Begin here](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources). Come back when you've read it. We expect prior research on SO. Good luck!

Comment: And that site you linked to is about Matlab, not C++...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a **`map<string, unsigned>`** to create a [**histogram**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram):

```
using std::string;
using std::map;
using std::vector;

typedef map<string, unsigned> counts_t;

// Create the histogram
counts_t histogram;
for (vector<string>::const_iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
    ++histogram[*i];

// ... and display it.
for (counts_t::const_iterator i = histogram.begin(); i != histogram.end(); ++i) {
    double freq = static_cast<double>(i->second) / vec.size();
    std::cout << i->first << ": " << freq << "\n";
}
```

Comment: frequency should be std::cout << i->first << ": " << i->second / vec.size() << "\n";

Comment: @chac: It is what the OP asked for, though.

Comment: @chac Uh … you’re of course right. I misread the question, is all.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't use unique, but for word counting it's hard to beat a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or any of its derivates, both in terms of memory usage & speed.