# Convert Array to new Array (counting occurrences)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of **n** number of items

```
var arr1 = [2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

as you see the array only has **i** different values `(v)` `(0,1,2),i = 3` in that case

What I would like is ending up with an array like this one.

```
var arr2 = [23, 45, 64]
```

the length of the arr2 array should corresponds to **i** and the values sould be the occurences of each value`(v)`

I am doing all kinds of loops and conditionals, but looking for a straight solution.
my part so far http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlebjoern/aSsjy/2/

jQuery and/or underscore may be involved.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-occurences-of-javascript-array-elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy peasy! The values of your input become the keys of your output; you accumulate on those keys as you encounter the values:

```
var arr1 = [0,0,0,1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,3,4,3,5];
var arr2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
   var n = arr1[i];
   if (arr2[n] != undefined)
       arr2[n]++;
   else
       arr2[n] = 1;
}

console.log(arr2);  // Output: [3, 1, 2, 5, 3, 1]
```

#### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/25Sqr/).

Comment: Close, but no cigar. The members of the array must be initialised as numbers (zero would be best). What you have returns `[,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]`.

Comment: @RobG: I did. And, no, it doesn't. Did you click on the link labelled "demo"? Or even read the code?

Comment: No, I pasted your original posted code into a browser. You've changed it so it works.

Comment: really good ... i didnt mention it, but there could also be a string in the initial array.

Comment: @RobG: About 15 seconds after posting, yes. That was 16 minutes  before your comment.

Comment: @Marcel: That completely changes things. Be more precise next time please. You will have to use an object rather than an array, then; fortunately you can probably just swap `var arr2 = []` for `var obj2 = {}` and be done with it.

Comment: 16 Minutes? I see only ~5 minute difference, giving you just enough time to edit your answer without it being shown to be edited. Must have made it by the skin of your teeth. :-)

Comment: Oh yes, I can't see where I got the 16 minute figure now. Still, you must not have been refreshing this page particularly often; as I said, the edit occurred _very_ quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a job for "reduce"

```
arr2 = arr1.reduce(function(a, v) {
    a[v] = (a[v] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
}, [])
```

Also, your `arr2` is actually associative, so it's better to use an object instead:

```
map = arr1.reduce(function(a, v) {
    a[v] = (a[v] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
}, {})
```

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is Javascript 1.8, for older browsers you need an emulation or use a library like underscore.js.

Example with underscore.js:

```
arr2 = _(arr1).chain().groupBy(_.identity).map(_.size).value()
```

This is perhaps not so "easy" as other answers, but at least you can learn something from this.

For the sake of being complete, here's the correct way to use a plain loop for the same task:

```
counter = [] // or {}
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
     counter[arr[i]] = (counter[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
```

Comment: His code explicitly states he wants an array, not a normal object.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit—which is likely why an answer with an array was given first, but an object suggested as a possibly more suitable option.

Comment: @RobG: It's given as part of a logical inference ("so") predicated on "your `arr2` is actually associative", which makes little sense when an explicit requirement was that it should no longer be. Still, apparently the question has since changed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other answer, here's one that works:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,3,4,3,5];
var arr2 = [];
var n, m;

for (var i=0, iLen=arr1.length; i < iLen; i++) {
  n = arr1[i];
  m = arr2[n];
  arr2[n] = m? ++m : 1;
}

alert(arr2)
```

Comment: It would be more readable to use `||` instead of the ternary operator: `arr2[n] = (arr2[n] || 0) + 1`

Comment: For some, whichever way suits. More to type though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_count_values:

```
<?php
     $array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
     print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

Comment: And use which javascript php live interpreter?

Comment: Congratulations on not bothering to read the question whatsoever.